# Why are we closing better question as a duplicate of worse question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I'm not sure if it's a SE wide policy, or only on SFF, but I'm used to duplicate policy being that a question with superior answers (especially if question itself is superior) is NOT closed as a duplicate of inferior one; even if it is posted chonologically later; and instead the worse one is closed as a dupe of a better later one.

So why was [Why is "In God We Trust" written on US currency?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/21953/why-is-in-god-we-trust-written-on-us-currency?noredirect=1&lq=1) with at least 2 great answers closed as a dupe of [Why Does USA Have So Many Religious References?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8521/why-does-usa-have-so-many-religious-references) and not vice versa?

Comment: Discussed on [meta.se] several times: [one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/187133), [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55251/187133), [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1375/187133). AFAIU, the solution is to merge these, albeit it might be unfair to one of the OPs.